# Order by distinct but then loop round

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My Data is :

(unique ID column on the right)

```
1. aaa,         1
2. aaa,         2
3. aaa,         3
4. bbb,         4
5. bbb,         5
6. bbb,         6
7. ccc,         7
8. ccc,         8
9. ccc,         9
10. ddd,        10
11. ddd,        11
12. ddd,        12
```

I want the results to be like

```
1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
4. ddd
5. aaa
6. bbb
7. ccc
8. ddd
9. aaa
10. bbb
11. ccc
12. ddd
```

I can cheat and use

```
Select distinct letters from table
UNION ALL
Select distinct letter from table
```

*repeat for each distinct xxx value

etc.. to get the right results but that relies on me knowing how many distinct values there are.

I think I'm missing something really simple here !

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, where do the extra rows come from?

Comment: removed the 4 rows. I got carried away copy/pasting..

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  This allows you to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by name order by id),
         id;
```

This does the interlaced ordering.  I'm not sure where the additional 4 rows are coming from.  The title of the question suggests that ordering is the basis of your question.

Comment: Thanks very much that works. It's not something I've needed to do and was wandering off into RANK and PARTITION BY !!